# How do I determine clipboard data size?

Tags: windows, winapi, clipboard

I have a custom data format in the clipboard (it is put there by a third-party program). 
I get the size of the data from the clipboard using:

```
HANDLE data = GetClipboardData(format);
DWORD len = GlobalSize(data);
```

The problem is, I get incorrect data size (about plus 100 bytes of what it actually should be). I mean, the size of real "valid" data in the clipboard is different. Moreover, I get different (!) data sizes from one call to another (although, the data itself does not change). Looks mysterious. I mean, if I just keep executing the above two lines in a loop, I'll be getting different values in "len" for this format.

So I have two questions basically...

1. How comes that "GlobalSize" may return non-constant values from one call to another for the very same data?
2. How do I get the "real" data size for the clipboard data in this format?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the MSDN page on the [`GlobalSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366593%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function:

> The size of a memory block may be larger than the size requested when
>   the memory was allocated

So you can not rely on `GlobalSize` to return the requested size of the allocation. Instead, you should pass the size as part of the data object itself (e.g. begin with a `DWORD` containing the size, followed by your data).

Comment: Thanks, but since it's not "mine" object I can't really modify data which is copied to clipboard.. Do I understand correctly, that this means, there is no way to determine the exact size of object which was actually copied to the clipboard?

Comment: That is correct.  Especially if it is a custom format, then the app that owns the format may be the only one who knows how to determine the data's actual size, if it even cares.

Comment: Nikolay, typically you use GlobalSize to know how much to allocate, and once you get the data, then you can trim it down to the actual size, probably after copying into a local variable or structure.  You have to know something about the data first, right?  Maybe it's null terminated, so you look for the first #0.  Maybe it has the length declared in the first few bytes.  Maybe something else, like CF_HTML where you have to read the start/length from a header before you can make sense out of it.